# Converting Wav in MP3

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I convert WAV in MP3 using QtMultimedia?

There is some specific class for reading WAV and writing MP3 files?

Comment: Does it have to use QtMultimedia?

Comment: Yes @FlorisVelleman! I believe QtMultimedia is the way, but the Documentation doesn't help to make it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no MP3 encoder packaged with Qt. You'll have to use an external library.

**Edit:** this is confirmed by [this thread](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13445) at least as far as Qt4 is concerned (no idea about Qt5 though but I suspect it's the same).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look for a little more. If I cannot use pure Qt, I will use Lame.